# C#, parsing data in a separate thread and updating GUI

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, user-interface, backgroundworker

everyone. Basically the workflow I want to implement goes as follows:

- Receive massive amount of data from a COM port;
- Save them into a [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);
- Asynchronously read lines from the ListBox and parse them into arrays of floats;
- Plot data on two separate [Charts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

Since the deadline is not so far, I started from an open source project called [Termie](http://termie.sourceforge.net/), which implements a simple serial interface also providing a comm configuration Form straight out of the box.
To perform multi-threaded operations, I'm using a [BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
private BackgroundWorker backgroundPressure = new BackgroundWorker();
```

Which I initialize in my main form's constructor method:

```
public consoleForm()
{
    ...
    // Initialize background worker to separate GUI from data collection
    backgroundPressure.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundPressure_DoWork);
    backgroundPressure.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(backgroundPressure_RunWorkerCompleted);
    backgroundPressure.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundPressure_ProgressChanged);
    backgroundPressure.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
    backgroundPressure.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
}
```

When transmission starts, the RunworkerAsync method of backgroundPressure is called:

```
if(!backgroundPressure.IsBusy)
{
    backgroundPressure.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

The DoWork event is properly handled and my program correctly enters the handler method which has the following code:

```
    protected void backgroundPressure_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker sendingWorker = (BackgroundWorker)sender;

        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            pressureChart.Series.Clear();
            pressureData.Clear();
            timeAxis.Clear();

            foreach (string name in pressureSensorNames)
            {
                pressureChart.Series.Add(name);
            }
        });

        Stopwatch sto = new Stopwatch();
        int linenumber = syncWithLogger("pres");

        int debugs = linenumber;

        while (linenumber == -1)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                linenumber = syncWithLogger("pres");
            });
        }

        sto.Start();

        long elapsed = sto.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        while (!sendingWorker.CancellationPending)
        {
            BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                try
                {
                    elapsed = sto.ElapsedMilliseconds;

                    pressureChartUpdate(linenumber, elapsed);
                    imuChartUpdate(linenumber + 1, elapsed);

                    linenumber += 2;
                    Thread.Sleep(100);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    if(ex is FormatException)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        // Wait and go on
                    }
                    else if(ex is ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
                    {
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        // Wait and go on
                    }
                }

            });

            sendingWorker.ReportProgress(10, 100);

            BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                samplesAcquiredStatus.Text = sto.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString();
            });


            e.Cancel = true;
            sto.Stop();

        }
    }
```

Everything works flawlessly until the `while (!sendingWorker.CancellationPending)` block. When it is entered, the GUI freezes and Visual Studio reports a progressive and fast increase in memory occupation, which I really don't understand, while no Exception is thrown.

[image: Memory occupation increase]

Such behaviour also occurs if I comment out the code which calls GUI updating methods

```
pressureChartUpdate(linenumber, elapsed);
imuChartUpdate(linenumber + 1, elapsed);
```

I've separately tested the parser, so I believe the issue stands in the multi-threaded operations. Can anyone help me?

Comment: One problem is calling Thread.Sleep on the UI thread - don't do that.

Comment: That was it, damn right! Thank you so, so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is calling `Thread.Sleep` on the UI thread. This will by definition block your UI and make it unresponsive. Once it is sleeping it can't perform an actions.

Comment: Yup, I just need to wait a few minutes to flag this answer with the good ol' green mark. By the way, is there any reason because when the GUI thread sleeps the memory occupation increases?

Comment: Shouldn't be a reason for that